# How to pass props to custom components in react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am trying to use a custom component as an input field in react-select. Since I need validation I am trying to use HTML5 `oninvalid` (`onInvalid` in JSX) for my input tag and set the custom message for `oninvalid`. However I am unable to pass the message as a prop to the component that I am setting in select. Below is my code.

Input.js

```
import React from "react";
import { components } from "react-select";

export default class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("component mounted");
  }
  setInvalidMessage = event => {
    event.target.setCustomValidity("Custom Message");
  };

  render() {
    if (this.props.isHidden) {
      return <components.Input {...this.props} />;
    }
    return (
      <components.Input
        {...this.props}
        required
        onInvalid={this.setInvalidMessage}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

example.js

```
import React from "react";
import Input from "./Input";
import Select from "react-select";
import { colourOptions } from "./docs/data";

const InputBoxWithText = props => {
  return <Input {...props} />;
};

export default () => (
  <form>
    <Select
      closeMenuOnSelect={true}
      components={{ InputBoxWithText }}
      options={colourOptions}
    />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
);
```

If I pass Input in components attribute I get the hard coded message in Input.js. If I pass InputBoxWithText I don't see Input mounting at all.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Example from './example';

ReactDOM.render(
<Example />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is [CodeSandBox.io URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/5y555yk2xl).

Can any one let me know if what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the solution (i'm looking for the same thing as well), but you example has multiple errors.

To load the input you have to write `components={{ Input: InputBoxWithText }}`, since the component name for `Input` is not `InputBoxWithText`.

Also the `onInvalid` does not seem to be part of the `Input` API, so it will never trigger. Are you trying to use the `<input oninvalid="" />`..?

Comment: You might have not known the answer but you have solved my problem. I overlooked the fact that components take an object as input. I changed the components to what you have answered and it is working as I expected. oninvalid for HTML is onInvalid in JSX. I assumed that react-select would be appending all the props that I pass on to the final input tag. So when react-select is rendered with custom Input tag it will have oninvalid set on the input tag.

Comment: Did you find solution for the original question?

Comment: @sebap I added an answer with an example, which might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 14):

It's better to pass custom props via select:

```
props.selectProps
```

To avoid re-creating of Custom component each time Select updates, what may cause unexpected bugs.

Comment: This is the correct answer, pass the needed props for a custom component to the main 'react-select' component.

The read them in your custom component with props.selectProps

Answer (score 8):

I managed to pass my custom props using an arrow function

[See docs](https://react-select.com/components#defining-components) for defining components

```
const Input = (inputProps: InputProps) => (
  <components.Input {...inputProps} />
);

<Select
  closeMenuOnSelect={true}
  options={colourOptions}
  components={{Input}}    
/>
```

Comment: Just a note - don't define components like this, always define them outside as mentioned in their documentation (due to performance and remounting): https://react-select.com/components#defining-components

Comment: This makes component loose focus and creates multiple other issues.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I was passing errors in such way:

```
        <Select
            defaultValue={values}
            selectProps={{ errors }}
            isMulti
            options={inventoryList}
            onChange={changeTreeElement}
            // @ts-ignore
            styles={colourStyles}
        />
```

Then access it like `selectProps.selectProps.errors` in [colourStyles methods](https://react-select.com/home#custom-styles).

Comment: In my case   const { originRoute } = props.selectProps.selectProps;
for this          selectProps={{ originRoute }}

Answer (score 6):

In version 5 the only way to use custom props with typescript is to use module augmentation.

So in my project I opened react-app-env.d.ts and added there this:

```
import { GroupBase } from 'react-select'

declare module 'react-select/dist/declarations/src/Select' {
  export interface Props<Option, IsMulti extends boolean, Group extends GroupBase<Option>> {
    customOnClear: () => void;
  }
}
```

You pass the prop to the select like this:

```
import Select from "react-select";

<Select customOnClear={() => {/* Your custom clear */} />
```

And use it in your custom component like this:

```
const ClearIndicator = ({ selectProps }: ClearIndicatorProps<Option, false>) => {
  const { customOnClear } = selectProps
  return <InputClear onClick={customOnClear} />
}
```

Docs:
https://react-select.com/typescript#custom-select-props