# How to pass array as result from one functional component to another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass data stored in `const mappedData` from `FetchDataComponent.js` to `ReactSelectComponent.js`. Is there any way of doing this with functional components?
With code under i get `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child`

FetchDataComponent.js

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import _ from "lodash";

const FetchDataComponent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({product: []})
    useEffect(
        () => {
            (async () => {
                const result = await axios.get(
                    '/products-data'
                )
                setData(result.data)
            })()
        }, [])

    console.log("data.product:")
    console.log(data.product)

    const mappedData = _.map(data.product, "proizvod_naziv")
    console.log("mappedData:")
    console.log(mappedData)
    console.log(typeof mappedData)

    return ({mappedData});
}

export default FetchDataComponent;
```

ReactSelectComponent.js

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

const ReactSelectComponent = () => {

    // place for data from FetchDataComponent.js
    const options = [
        {
            // value: ,
            // label: 
        },
        {value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry'},
        {value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla'}
    ]

    return (<Select options={options}/>)

}
export default ReactSelectComponent;
```

console.log(mappedData):

```
(3) […]
​0: "M-Z-8Nm"
​1: "M-P-10Nm"
​2: "V-H"
​length: 3
​<prototype>: Array []
```

console.log(typeof mappedData):

```
object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FetchDataComponent` is not really a react component since it does not render anything. It looks more like this is custom hook. To make that a hook, just make it simple function that calls other hooks:

```
const useFetchedData = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ product: [] })
    useEffect(
        () => {
            (async () => {
                const result = await axios.get(
                    '/products-data'
                )
                setData(result.data)
            })()
        }, [])

    const mappedData = _.map(data.product, "proizvod_naziv")

    return mappedData
}

export default useFetchedData;
```

And now you can use that hook's return value to get the data you want and pass that to other components.

```
const ReactSelectComponent = () => {
    const mappedData = useFetchedData()
    const options = mappedData.map(value => ({ value, label: value }))
    return (<Select options={options}/>)
}
export default ReactSelectComponent;
```

[Read more about custom hooks here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass props to `react-select`  see this answer for example:

```
<Select
  closeMenuOnSelect={true}
  options={colourOptions}
  components={{
    Input: (inputProps: InputProps) => (
      <components.Input {...inputProps} />
    ),
  }}    
/>
```

[How to pass props to custom components in react-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52551786/how-to-pass-props-to-custom-components-in-react-select)

Also you must return `JSX` from react components.